# Why when I am submiting an answer javascript is always displaying false?

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem with displaying true/false after submiting an answer to question.

I need to display true when answer is true e.g.( 14+1=15 true), but my code is always displaying false and never displays true.
Hope you will understand my code.

p.s. to display question press answer, in start it doesn't display question.

```js
function myfunc() {
    //randomizer + - * /
    var symbol;

    var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    if (s === 1) {
        symbol = '+';
    }
    if (s === 2) {
        symbol = '-';
    }
    if (s === 3) {
        symbol = '*';
    }
    if (s === 4) {
        symbol = '/';
    }
    //first num randomizer
    var firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    //sec num randomizer
    var secnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = firstnum + symbol + secnum;
    //answer filter
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var testanswer;
    if (s === 1) {
        testanswer = firstnum + secnum;
    }
    if (s === 2) {
        testanswer = firstnum - secnum;
    }
    if (s === 3) {
        testanswer = firstnum * secnum;
    }
    if (s === 4) {
        testanswer = firstnum / secnum;
    }
    //test answerer
    if (testanswer === input) {
        document.getElementById('atbilde').innerHTML = 'true';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('atbilde').innerHTML = 'false';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <input id="input" type="text">
        <button id="mybt" type="button" onclick="myfunc()">submit</button><br>
        <p id="atbilde"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `input` will always be a string, where as `testanswer` is a number so `===` will always be false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, randomizing * 5 for 4 symbols is incorrect. Also, try to compare the answer to the actual numbers, not to the newly generated one.

```js
var last = null;
myfunc();

function myfunc() {
  //randomizer + - * /
  var symbol;

  var s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  if (s === 1) {
    symbol = '+';
  }
  if (s === 2) {
    symbol = '-';
  }
  if (s === 3) {
    symbol = '*';
  }
  if (s === 4) {
    symbol = '/';
  }
  //first num randomizer
  var firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  //sec num randomizer
  var secnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = firstnum + symbol + secnum;
  //answer filter
  var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

  var testanswer;
  if (s === 1) {
    testanswer = firstnum + secnum;
  }
  if (s === 2) {
    testanswer = firstnum - secnum;
  }
  if (s === 3) {
    testanswer = firstnum * secnum;
  }
  if (s === 4) {
    testanswer = firstnum / secnum;
  }

  if (last != null) {
    if (last == input && input != '') {
      document.getElementById('atbilde').innerHTML = 'true';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('atbilde').innerHTML = 'false';
    }
  }
  last = testanswer;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myfunc(); return false">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <input id="input" type="text">
  <button id="mybt" type="submit">submit</button><br>
  <p id="atbilde"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to separate generating questions from checking answers. I modified your code and added some comments:

HTML

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="input" type="text">
<button id="mybt" type="button" onclick="checkAnswer()">submit</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="showQuestion()">Show New Question</button><br>
<p id="atbilde"></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var s, firstnum, secnum;

  // first, show an initial question for a start
  showQuestion();

  // this method is used to show initial question and also to "Show New Question" when that button is pressed
  function showQuestion(){
      //randomizer + - * /
      let symbol;

      // changed formula to return 1, 2, 3, or 4. It was also returning 0 and 5 previously.
      s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      if (s === 1) {
          symbol = '+';
      }
      if (s === 2) {
          symbol = '-';
      }
      if (s === 3) {
          symbol = '*';
      }
      if (s === 4) {
          symbol = '/';
      }

      //first num randomizer
      firstnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      //sec num randomizer
      secnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = firstnum + symbol + secnum;
  }

  // when the user is ready and clicks submit, we check the answer using s, firstnum, and secnum
  function checkAnswer() {
      //answer filter
      var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
      var testanswer;
      if (s === 1) {
          testanswer = firstnum + secnum;
      }
      if (s === 2) {
          testanswer = firstnum - secnum;
      }
      if (s === 3) {
          testanswer = firstnum * secnum;
      }
      if (s === 4) {
          testanswer = firstnum / secnum;
      }

      console.log('the answer is supposed to be ', testanswer, ' and the user submitted ', testanswer);

      //test answer
      // I changed === to == this way you can compare a string "100" to the number 100 and it will be true.
      // Because "100" === 100 is false (it checks the type) and "100" == 100 is true (does not check the type.)
      if (testanswer == input) {
          document.getElementById('atbilde').innerHTML = 'true';
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById('atbilde').innerHTML = 'false';
      }
  }
```